# Why is my custom Json.net converter not working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, json.net, deserialization

Since GameObjects cannot be serialized I wrote a class that holds the name of the GameObject so that it can find it by the name. However I am getting this error during deserialization and I can't figure out why.

> JsonSerializationException: Type specified in JSON 'GameObjectReferencer, SaveSystem, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not compatible with 'UnityEngine.GameObject, UnityEngine.CoreModule, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Path 'wrappedSaveDatas.$values[4].savedObject.other.$type', line 338, position 55.

This is my Custom converter:

```
public class GameObjectFromReferenceConverter : JsonConverter
{
public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
{       return objectType == typeof(GameObjectReferencer);
}

public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{        throw new Exception("GameObjectFromReferenceConverter should only be used when loading");
}


public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    GameObjectReferencer goRef = (GameObjectReferencer)reader.Value;

    
    return ((GameObjectReferencer)goRef).GetGameObject();
}
}
```

This is my Referencer class:

```
 public class GameObjectReferencer
{
public string targetGameObjectName;

public GameObjectReferencer(string gameObjectName)
{
    this.targetGameObjectName = gameObjectName;  
}

public GameObject GetGameObject()
{
    GameObject go = GameObject.Find(targetGameObjectName);
    if (go == null)
        throw new System.Exception("Can't find object with the name " + targetGameObjectName);
    return go;
}

public override string ToString()
{
    return "GameObjectReference of \"" + targetGameObjectName+ "\"";
}

public static GameObjectReferencer GenerateReference(GameObject gameObject)
{
    return new GameObjectReferencer(gameObject.name);
}

}
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642857/c-sharp-net-deserialization-type-not-working) will help you

Comment: Do you control your JSON format?  If not, what does your JSON look like?

Comment: But possibly related: [How can I custom serialize a GameObject reference by its GUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39794955).

Comment: Also, what is the declared type of `wrappedSaveDatas[].savedObject.other`?  Is it `GameObject` or `object`?  Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: check the json maybe it for the syntax of it

Comment: @dbc It is just a bunch of object holding array of another objects holding another object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GameObjectReferencer` is an example of a [DTO (data transfer object)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)

> a data transfer object (DTO) is an object that carries data between processes.

Since serialization and deserialization need to have a consistent format, that generally means that your DTO must get used for both.  Thus your converter should look something like the following:

```
public class GameObjectFromReferenceConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => 
        typeof(GameObject).IsAssignableFrom(objectType); 

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        serializer.Serialize(writer, GameObjectReferencer.GenerateReference((GameObject)value));

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        serializer.Deserialize<GameObjectReferencer>(reader)?.GetGameObject();
}

// Serialization DTO class for GameObject and derived types.
class GameObjectReferencer
{
    public string targetGameObjectName { get; set; }

    public GameObjectReferencer(string targetGameObjectName) => this.targetGameObjectName = targetGameObjectName;

    public GameObject GetGameObject() =>
        GameObject.Find(targetGameObjectName) ?? throw new System.Exception("Can't find object with the name " + targetGameObjectName);

    public static GameObjectReferencer GenerateReference(GameObject gameObject) => new GameObjectReferencer(gameObject.name);

    public override string ToString() => "GameObjectReference of \"" + targetGameObjectName+ "\"";
}
```

And you must also use the converter in settings for both serialization and deserialization, e.g. like so:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new GameObjectFromReferenceConverter() },
    // Other settings as required, e.g.:
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
};
```

Notes:

- When serializing with a converter, the converter must take care of **all aspects** of serialization and deserialization, including serialization and deserialization of `$type` metadata.  Thus converters do not necessarily play well with Json.NET's [`TypeHandHandling` setting](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializetypenamehandling.htm).
- When deserializing, the `objectType` passed to `JsonConverter.CanConvert(objectType)` will be the declared type of the object to be deserialized.  Since the declared type of any `GameObject` reference will typically be `GameObject` or some subtype, in `CanConvert` you need to check that the type is assignable from `GameObject` not `GameObjectReferencer`.

  When serializing the `objectType` will be the actual, concrete type being serialized, which will, again, be some subtype of `GameObject`.
- Inside `ReadJson()` the value of [`JsonReader.Value`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_Value.htm) will be the value of the current json **token**.  When the current token is [`JsonToken.StartObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonToken.htm) (i.e. positioned on the `{` token), `JsonReader.Value` will be `null`.
- For Json.NET to successfully deserialize a type using a parameterized constructor, the constructor argument names must match the property names (here `targetGameObjectName`).
- When using `TypeNameHandling`, do take note of this caution from the [Newtonsoft docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm):

  > TypeNameHandling should be used with caution when your application deserializes JSON from an external source. Incoming types should be validated with a custom SerializationBinder when deserializing with a value other than None.

  For a discussion of why this may be necessary, see *[TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954/3744182)*.
- For a similar converter using GUIDs instead of names, see *[How can I custom serialize a GameObject reference by its GUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39794955)*.

Mockup fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZQGEnT).

Comment: If I am not mistaken you have only reformatted my GameObjectReferencer class. 

This answer probably solved my problem but I am dealing with different errors. I will return back and accept the answer If I can run the code.

Comment: @WVrock Most of my changes were in `GameObjectFromReferenceConverter`.  In `GameObjectReferencer` I made the constructor name and property name be consistent, which Json.NET requires.

Comment: The code is working as intended. At first I used 1 converter for serializing from game object to DTO and 1 converter for deserializing from DTO to gameobject. The error was seemed to be caused by not having both the dto and gameobject returning true for canConvert method. However even adding it caused some token error so I had to use the same converter for both deserializin and serializing just like you have said.

Thank you for the help.